# grunt Error: Cannot find module 'imagemin-pngquant'

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to run grunt command but when i do, this error shows up:

MacBook-Pro-de-Paulo:homedesigners PauloDuarte$ grunt
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR

> > Error: Cannot find module 'imagemin-pngquant'

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

public/modules/landing/directives/scrollOnClick.client.directive.js
     13 |          $target = $(idToScroll);
                             ^ '$' is not defined.
     17 |        $('body').animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top});
                 ^ '$' is not defined.

> > 2 errors in 55 files
> >     Fatal error: Invalid URI ""
> >     MacBook-Pro-de-Paulo:homedesigners PauloDuarte$

Anyone can help? thanks

Comment: Did you try _npm install --save imagemin-pngquant_ ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try installing the required module using npm:

```
npm install imagemin-pngquant
```